# Can I somehow use the airflow S3 sensor to create a DAG which will run everytime a new file is uploaded?

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, amazon-redshift, airflow-2.x

I am trying to build a dag which should trigger a Redshift copy command every time a new file is uploaded on the S3 folder. I tried using S3 Key sensor but it runs only once and then the dag is successful. Also I need to know the file which triggered the sensor so that my copy command can load the file.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.s3 import S3KeySensor
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.s3 import S3CopyObjectOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.transfers.s3_to_redshift import S3ToRedshiftOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('dag_google_marketing_spends', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)


s3_sensor = S3KeySensor(
    task_id='s3_sensor',
    bucket_name='my_bucket',
    bucket_key='folder/*.csv',
    wildcard_match=True,
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    timeout=180,
    dag=dag
)
```